# log2 for max int and long values

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Why do I get wrong results with `log2 (ULONG_MAX)` and `log2 (ULLONG_MAX)`? I was expecting 63 but got 64.

```
UINT32_MAX == pow(2, 32) - 1
```

so `log2(UINT32_MAX) == 31`, (not 32!)

```
ULLONG_MAX == pow(2, 64) - 1
```

so I would expect `log2(ULLONG_MAX) == 63`

but I got 64. Why?

```
 // 15
 printf ("u_int16: %d\n", (int)log2 (UINT16_MAX));
 // 31
 printf ("u_int:   %d\n", (int)log2 (UINT32_MAX));

 // 64
 printf ("ul_int:  %d\n", (int)log2 (ULONG_MAX));
 // 64
 printf ("ull_int: %d\n", (int)log2 (ULLONG_MAX));
```

Comment: Those numbers probably can't be represented exactly by a double on your system.

Comment: `log2` is for floating point and can lose precision.  For integers this is equivalent to finding the most significant 1 bit.  There's no standard C function for this, but you can find some algorithms and compiler-specific approaches here: [Fast computing of log2 for 64-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376288/fast-computing-of-log2-for-64-bit-integers)

Comment: @NateEldredge: (a) `log2` may lose accuracy, but it does not lose precision: The input precision, `double`, is exactly the same as the output precision, `double`. (b) The accuracy of `log2` is not a factor in this question. The change in value occurs before `log2` executes.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR:

If you want to get the position of the highest 1 bit then you're doing it completely wrong with the slowest and most error-prone way. See the solution at the end

---

[`log2()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/log2) receives a `double`, but `long` and `long long` in your platform have 64 bits of precision, which is far more than `double` can store, as it's probably [IEEE-754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) and has only 53 significant bits. The closest to `ULLONG_MAX` in `double` is *ULLONG_MAX + 1.0 = 2<sup>64</sup>* and obviously *log2(ULLONG_MAX) = log2(2<sup>64</sup>) = 64*. You can never get 63 by using `double` like that

If you want to get the base 2 logarithm of such numbers then you'll need a type with more precision like `long double` on some platforms, and also a good `log2` library (see below for why that matters). On x86 `long double` is usually [80-bit extended precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision) with 64 significant bits and can store `ULLONG_MAX` without problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <quadmath.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
  printf("sizeof(long)        = %zu\n", sizeof(long));
  printf("sizeof(long long)   = %zu\n", sizeof(long long));
  printf("sizeof(double)      = %zu\n", sizeof(double));
  printf("sizeof(long double) = %zu\n", sizeof(long double));
  printf("double      has %d significant bits\n", DBL_MANT_DIG);
  printf("long double has %d significant bits\n", LDBL_MANT_DIG);
  printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
  
  printf("ULONG_MAX               = %lu\n", ULONG_MAX);
  printf("ULLONG_MAX              = %llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);
  printf("(double)ULONG_MAX       = %f\n", (double)ULONG_MAX);
  printf("(double)ULLONG_MAX      = %f\n", (double)ULLONG_MAX);
  printf("(long double)ULONG_MAX  = %Lf\n", (long double)ULONG_MAX);
  printf("(long double)ULLONG_MAX = %Lf\n", (long double)ULLONG_MAX);
  printf("-----------------------------------------------------\n");
  
  printf("ul_int (double):\t\t\t%d\n", (int)log2(ULONG_MAX));
  printf("ull_int (double):\t\t\t%d\n", (int)log2(ULLONG_MAX));

  printf("ul_int (long double):\t\t\t%d\n", (int)log2l((long double)ULONG_MAX)); 
  printf("ull_int (long double):\t\t\t%d\n", (int)log2l((long double)ULLONG_MAX));
  printf("ul_int (18446744073709551615.0L):\t%d\n",
          (int)log2l(18446744073709551615.0L));

  printf("ul_int (__float128):\t\t\t%d\n", (int)log2q((__float128)ULONG_MAX));
  printf("ull_int (__float128):\t\t\t%d\n", (int)log2q((__float128)ULLONG_MAX));
  printf("ull_int (18446744073709551615.0q):\t%d\n",
          (int)log2q(18446744073709551615.0q));
}
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlJvoCqAZ0wAFAB4gA5AAYppAFZdSrZrVDIApACYAQjt2kR7ZATx1KmWugDCqVgFcAtrRDcZpK%2BgAyeWpgA5ZwAjTGIubVIAB1QhQnNaO0cXNw8YuLM6X38gp1DwzkjjTFMEhgJmYgIk51d3I0wTTNpyyoJswJCwiKMKqpqU%2BqE%2B9r9OvO7CgEojVAdiZA4pHQBmP2RHLABqTRWbYfxUADoEXexNGQBBVfXNzB29p2YCBBOzi%2BvtNdoNh23dmwARwczHQTxebxW5yuNx%2BdweNlYeCchCEkOhn2%2Bv3%2BeyorFQz3RHw%2BfgIWyefggU2JAHZ9FctoytlFiKSqBAdNo4gAvTCodn49RTJkih4AER22gArNyHJopTZaJzSFseXyBXRgFNqSt6ZcRSy2RztFy8Lz%2BRBBcAtlbhYzdhKdDK5QqlSaVWqLVabZrtbs9QbWfR2ZzPez0HNguw7SKHZLnfLFcrVWb1RAIw4o5g/bqPoGjaHU17NVsM1nhXGnbLE27IinzRr1KXI9GdQGmYbg8btGX2KKtghmEJ4%2BgU8BaHgqHgWPQtsFUTXk2LdN4APoAWUuAQAKquxQBJADibbzHaDBBDJu9vfug%2BHTtHcXHk%2BnajJ84IQkX7q23mXa83Hc9yPE8GTPAsTQAWmgmDYLg%2BCEMQpDEO/bRQP1JlT0ZTsL27ARvAAeQCQ8N0uAANftKPtFZHWlRxUJVfCiJIzcyPQ/Mu05fDCOI0iKKo0VKzo%2BjXWTbjmL49jwM4k10xbbMmN41jKKEqUqAYrY5MzaNFJY8ipOw89L20LTy3EpTyP7VT1NEn9TJ07weL0tj/Sw5kjO7S0SxvKZdL46jaKlbwbKTOzr3k3ynMk1ywMMiCTPC7SFMciTlNU4KNK8psfPM5yDPc%2BLkKK4qSoQ1D8rcnDjIcVhV1JTSfJARMCGa1rpXQTLSSmfFgBMvzWJzds4pk7Qatq%2Br7OzJqFRama2qlDrbLrCAup6vqUostj0MqjzORqurZyy61Gtaua5vazr6G61BetYKBErMqKBrbHZYoKkaxoOskjubJKpmmmxZsB%2BbFtC5bVpu7Q7p%2BnKNry/Kqu7faJs4AAObhuAANhpDGZBpFYaRkABOKUpU4THOClI4ZG8f6QYYtyqJWq61rutGMex3H8cJkmyYpqmacG4k3sRvbxsO1dVzxAkCEKVG6bO4HzoWy6CGu3rASgSXpeeOXItS/SEd2k1Pom7X8V17R5YBoHbYfVX1e0TWIHNmW9dyySjfi03DvZrGcfcbnidJ8nKepwEFeBi6ltIRnKOZtW1s1v3OcDgng75sOZAj7aaTFD4pBmVhpCleRXFkeRUGkGwDAMVU5gWe5Vk4eQCGkORtVIABrNxMaOAnuCJtGVildxyaJ9GVGkbgy/byvpHkIQQA8NuK5mOBYBgRAUFQJwojwdgyAoCA0D3g/umATgr74A%2BCDCJeIGCOfSHnWhKgAT2f0%2BnCsAgCNoVgn8K6kCwE8dQ7Bn74GICUMwAA3TAS9gGYHECUBwd9n6kkaM/JEwRiAfzsFgZ%2BBBWROGkC3GY/BGAsAgTwPgdACDCDEJIYBShOAqDUBoWuegVB4GCEvSAMxUBRGaIgyCBFtBbEgqwYEoJwQIEkQAdTYKwRRyDiHMEkVQNRkFaDODCNOKRhAwhsCEIvRoMCEiWGsAMVwbCvAdFyPkEAKxoixHiHQGxyh0juNoA4ro4QXHFFKHQVo/R7C1GUEE5ooTRg5H8c43obRPFsOGG0PxEwAkzCEA3RYXAi4l1nsAquUhxCo0xpBTG3AtjAGQMgLYV8jicE0rgQgJBJQrDYVsOwZ9D7tM4MKGuegDCtznp3HuUoPDFykDPUgpDuDaCODjNGMhMak24DSKUFMSakHLnIUgxTF7L1IKvDupAN7bzmAQKIaDyCUFPvvQ%2ByhMD4CIAUOh9AmBsA4LQyhjCJDPwAO54KiGQwuU8pClx2c/YpzctgAsIPI0p5TKnVNqfUzgjSRlrxmAgTAoJuhUnBTM0hUoaRHGlKjTgRMVgYylNobgKxKVQqKQvIwRyTmFxmOMlYRxMbShkJSypUoJ4rBkOTcFKxCl7IOcc0Z%2BSpDaClfPKQWKO4zHgcQOIFhuBAA%3D). Sample output:

```
sizeof(long)        = 8
sizeof(long long)   = 8
sizeof(double)      = 8
sizeof(long double) = 16
double      has 53 significant bits
long double has 64 significant bits
-----------------------------------------------------
ULONG_MAX               = 18446744073709551615
ULLONG_MAX              = 18446744073709551615
(double)ULONG_MAX       = 18446744073709551616.000000
(double)ULLONG_MAX      = 18446744073709551616.000000
(long double)ULONG_MAX  = 18446744073709551615.000000
(long double)ULLONG_MAX = 18446744073709551615.000000
-----------------------------------------------------
ul_int (double):                    64
ull_int (double):                   64
ul_int (long double):               64
ull_int (long double):              64
ul_int (18446744073709551615.0L):   64
ul_int (__float128):                63
ull_int (__float128):               63
ull_int (18446744073709551615.0q):  63
```

Notice that `ULONG_MAX` can't be represented in `double` precision as I mentioned previously. But also notice that **even in `long double` we get `log2l(18446744073709551615.0L) = 64`!!!** Only `__float128` which is libquadmath's [IEEE-754 quadruple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) works. Why? Because `log` and other transcendental functions are very complex and aren't required to be faithfully rounded by IEEE-754, so implementations are allowed to use a much faster algorithm but may return some results with 1ULP error. The result on Godbolt above is for glibc and you need to find some better `log2` library as I said above. See

- [Floating point accuracy with different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58411805/995714)
- [Math precision requirements of C and C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20945815/995714)
- [Why do sin(45) and cos(45) give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31509019/995714)
- [Why do I get platform-specific result for std::exp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54250126/995714)

## Update:

As commented by chux below, the result **might be faithfully rounded** in this case but unfortunately the closest `long double` value to log<sub>2</sub>18446744073709551615 = [63.999999999999999999921791345121706111...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2%2818446744073709551615%29) is 64.0L

That means you still need higher precision to get the expected output

---

But probably you're doing it the wrong way. If you just want to [get the position of the highest 1 bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set) then **never use `log2()`!!!** It's super slow and is prone to floating-point errors like above. Most architectures have an instruction to get the result in 1 or a few cycles. In C++20 just use [`std::bit_width(x)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countl_zero) or the equivalent

```
return std::numeric_limits<T>::digits - std::countl_zero(x);
```

In older C++ versions you can use [`boost::multiprecision::msb(x)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/gen_int.html), [`boost::static_log2(x)`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/log2.html). In C you'll need implementation-specific solutions like

- [`__builtin_clz`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) in GCC and Clang
- [`_BitScanReverse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/bitscanreverse-bitscanreverse64?view=msvc-160) in MSVC
- [`_bit_scan_reverse`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/intrinsics/intrinsics-for-all-intel-architectures/miscellaneous-intrinsics.html) in ICC

There are also other fast bitwise solutions in

- [What is the fastest/most efficient way to find the highest set bit (msb) in an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/671815/995714)
- [Fast computing of log2 for 64-bit integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11376288/995714)
- [Find the highest order bit in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53161/995714)
- [How to get position of right most set bit in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31393100/995714)

Comment: I have doubts about "Because log and other transcendental functions aren't required to be faithfully rounded by IEEE-754" applies here.  `log2l(18446744073709551615.0L)` is 64.0L and not the next smaller `long double`  of `63.9999999999999999 9653...L` because  64.0L is the closer answer - within 0.5 ULP of the correct answer `63.9999999999999999 9992...`.  As I see it, the answer is faithfully rounded.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yeah that might be the issue. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

`log2` is declared `double log2(double)`; it takes a `double` argument and produces a `double` result. When `log2(ULLONG_MAX)` is evaluated, `ULLONG_MAX` is converted to `double`.

The format commonly used for `double` has 53 bits in the significand (the fraction portion of a floating-point representation). Representing `ULLONG_MAX` requires 63 bits. So `ULLONG_MAX` cannot be represented in `double`. Instead, the conversion produces the nearest value that is representable, which is 2<sup>64</sup>.

Then `log2` applied to 2<sup>64</sup> produces 64.

You can see this by printing `ULLONG_MAX` before and after conversion to `double`:

```
printf("%llu\n", ULLONG_MAX);
printf("%.0f\n", (double) ULLONG_MAX);
```

prints:

```
18446744073709551615
18446744073709551616
```

Comment: I tried log2l-function. It takes long double values - the same problem. but  ULLONG_MAX is much smaller than LDBL_MAX.

Comment: @top-of-stack: The `long double` format is not more precise than `double` in every C implementation. After including `<float.h>`, you can print `DBL_MANT_DIG` and `LDBL_MANT_DIG` to see how many digits are in the significant of each and `FLT_RADIX` to see what base the digits are in (likely 2). If you get 53 for both `DBL_MANT_DIG` and `LDBL_MANT_DIG`, then they are the same precision in your C implementation. If you get a bigger number for `LDBL_MANT_DIG`, then show exact code that demonstrates your results.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get wrong results with `log2(ULONG_MAX)` and `log2(ULLONG_MAX)`? I was expecting 63 but got 64.

Insufficient precision in 2 steps and rounding.

---

`ULLONG_MAX` or 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 or 2<sup>64</sup>-1 converts to 18,446,744,073,709,551,616.0 *before* being when passed to `double log2(double)`. The result is 64.0 which is math correct for log2(2<sup>64</sup>)

---

> I tried log2l-function. It takes long double values - the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559309/log2-for-max-int-and-long-values/67585434#comment119413442_67559486).

With [80-bit "double extended" extended precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#IEEE_754_extended_precision_formats) with its 64-bit precision, `ULLONG_MAX` coverts to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615.0L when passed to `long double log2l(long double)`. The result is still 64.0L as 64.0L is the best `long double` answer with that encoding.

```
64.0                       long double
63.99999999999999999992... math log2(18,446,744,073,709,551,615)
63.99999999999999999653... next smaller long double
```

---

To get a `log2(ULLONG_MAX)` to produce a good result less than 64 (which `(int)` truncates to 63), the floating point encoding needs:

- At least 64-bit precision to accommodate the exact conversion of `ULLONG_MAX`.
- At least about 69-bit precision to form a rounded answer less than 64.0.